# SonarQube Scanner execution fails in Jenkins with java.lang.IllegalStateException Error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonarqube Build Environment details as follows:

```
SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
Sonar-scanner Version - 3.0.3.778 (running through “Execute SonarQube Scanner” in Jenkins)
sonar-java-plugin-4.14.0.11784.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.6.0.jar
Build Mode: Jenkins - (Version-2.46.2-LTS)
Build: Maven
```

**Problem Description:**

The `sonar-project.properties` declared in Jenkins itself. While analyzing it fails with below errors.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.config.Settings
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:272)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:112)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:140)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.repository.ProjectRepositories
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://100.101.102.103:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=scm.sesi.sm.ds
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
    at org.sonar.batch.repository.DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.load(DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider.provide(ProjectRepositoriesProvider.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 37 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
```

`sonar.log` file error as follows

```
2017.10.11 05:03:13 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://100.101.102.103:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=scm.sesi.sm.ds
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.protobuf.ByteString.copyFromUtf8(ByteString.java:321) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.escapeText(TextFormat.java:1892) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printFieldValue(TextFormat.java:428) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printSingleField(TextFormat.java:368) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printField(TextFormat.java:327) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:314) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printFieldValue(TextFormat.java:450) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printSingleField(TextFormat.java:368) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printField(TextFormat.java:324) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:314) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.access$400(TextFormat.java:288) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.shortDebugString(TextFormat.java:113) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonarqube.ws.MessageFormatter.print(MessageFormatter.java:32) ~[sonar-ws-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WsUtils.writeProtobuf(WsUtils.java:63) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.batch.ProjectAction.handle(ProjectAction.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:107) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D0262463297.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:34) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
```

I have tried the below to solve this issue,

```
1) Rebooted the server then re-installed all the plugins. 
2) Cleared the $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es folder 
3) Switched the quality profile(First default then changed to custom profile).
```

However still same problem persists, Now only thing pending is that I need to delete the $SONARQUBE_HOME/temp/*.* data from sonarqube server then after reboot I need to check the analyze.

Comment: Did you find any error/warning in `$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log` file? You can try to find there text equal to `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Actually I have access.log and sonar.log in $SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/ directory, sonar.log shows same errors,which is already given below.

Comment: It is weird that `sonar.log` contains logs from scanner execution. The bug must be there. Please attach that file.

Comment: sonar.log errors added in question category.

Comment: Unfortunately too little data to solve the problem. I did some research and they may be several reasons: database is inconsistent, invalid encoding (e.g. between SonarQube and database), broken quality profile (you can try to use default quality profile and switch to yours after "first" analysis), missing files etc. You can try to reinstall all plugins, stop server and remove all temporary files, start server, do first analysis with default profiles and finally use your profiles. You can also try to analyze your maven project by the maven scanner instead of the standalone scanner.

Comment: Hi Agabrys, today I have tried the below, 1)Rebooted the server then re-installed all the plugins. 2) Cleared the $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es folder 3) Switched the quality profile(First default then changed to custom profile) however still same problem persists, Now only thing pending is that I need to delete the $SONARQUBE_HOME/temp/*.* data from sonar server then after reboot I need to check the analyze.

Comment: Even deleted the temp folder from $SONARQUBE_HOME folder and tried. Still same problem. Other projects working fine. Problem only for this project.

Comment: You can try to analyze this project under different projectKey. If it will work, then probably your only chance to fix it is to delete the `scm.sesi.sm.ds` project and analyze it again.

Comment: projectKey=scm.sesi.sm.ds with new name already tried however issue is same. Instead of deleting i have created new project name and project key that worked.

Comment: Today tried on SonarQube-5.6.7(LTS) version as well, However still it fails with same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is 100.101.102.103 really the IP address of your SonarQube server? If so, you might have forgotten the `sonar` context path in the URL somewhere in your configuration.

It should probably be something like:

```
http://100.101.102.103:9000/sonar
```

Instead of:

```
http://100.101.102.103:9000/
```

Comment: Our Sonarqube Server URL is – http://100.101.102.103:9000/  and same has been already configured in our sonar-scanner.properties file as well.

Comment: What about the `/sonar`? Is that part of your `sonar.host.url`?

Comment: If you reach SonarQube via `http://100.101.102.103:9000/sonar` then you should also configure the `sonar.host.url` like that.

Comment: I have not added  sonar.web.context=/sonar in our sonar.properties file. So our sonar URL is - http://100.101.102.103:9000/, Same is working fine for other projects. Now problem only for particular project.

Comment: The following actions have been tried already.
1) Rebooted the Sonar server and deleted the es directory from Sonarqube home folder, then started the service.
2) Tried with sonar-java-plugin-4.13.0.11627.jar file, still problem is same.

Comment: From Soar Server (sonar.log) file shows 2017.10.10 05:03:14 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://100.101.102.103:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=scm.sesi.sm.ds java.lang.NullPointerException: null error.

Comment: If it's not a configuration issue, then I start to get out of ideas... :(

Comment: With Old name (Not working)
sonar.projectKey=scm.sesi.sm.‌​ds
sonar.projectName=SCM_SESI_SM-DS

whereas with new name it works.
sonar.projectKey=scm.sesi.sm.‌​ds_new
sonar.projectName=SCM_SESI_SM-DS_new

i don't want to delete the old project,else all old project history will be lost.

Comment: You should be able to rename the project key via the SonarQube Web UI

Comment: Renamed the sonar.projectKey with new name over sonar web and tried the analysis, still same problem.

Comment: Shall I delete the $SONARQUBE_HOME/temp/*.* data from sonar server then reboot the server and try the analysis through Jenkins?

Comment: Error from server sonar.log  at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
 at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
 at rubyjit.Rack::Handler::Servlet$$call_8E7740794C2C9B2AA48C4FF36A45D7CC91DA0560262463297.__file__(file:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be fixed in version 6.5. See [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9423) issue. Alternatively, you can delete your project and it will be recreated without issues.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information Chadi. I have deleted that project and created new project it started working fine. Anyway in future if i face the same problem i will check it on latest LTS version.